# freeradius stops working after some time

Tags: active-directory, ubuntu-14.04, freeradius

I've got freeradius 2.1.12 running under Ubuntu 14.04, authenticating against a Windows 2012 Active Directory controller. While working fine most of the time, it may happen after a few days of running that suddenly *valid* users fail to authenticate. The log may then show things like

```
Login incorrect (mschap: External script says ): [john.doe] (from client myclient port 0 via TLS tunnel)
Login incorrect: [john.doe] (from client myclient port 1 cli 20-E4-A2-67-8D-4A)
```

Note that a "really" wrong login would have some explanation like `(mschap: External script says Logon failure (0xc000006d))` in it.
Restarting the freeradius service helps, but why does this happen in the first place?

**EDIT:** Upon closer inspection of common events, it appears that the failure begins to occur (if at all) in the morning right with the first login attempt after a daily SIGHUP:

```
08:04:33 2016 : Info: HUP - loading modules
08:04:33 2016 : Info:  Module: Reloaded module "attr_filter.access_reject"
08:04:33 2016 : Info:  Module: Reloaded module "attr_filter.accounting_response"
08:04:33 2016 : Info:  Module: Reloaded module "pap"
08:04:34 2016 : Info:  Module: Reloaded module "radutmp"
08:04:34 2016 : Info:  Module: Reloaded module "suffix"
08:04:34 2016 : Info:  Module: Reloaded module "files"
08:04:34 2016 : Info:  Module: Reloaded module "detail"
08:04:34 2016 : Info:  Module: Reloaded module "mschap"
08:04:34 2016 : Info: Loaded virtual server <default>
08:04:34 2016 : Info: Loaded virtual server inner-tunnel
10:39:00 2016 : Error:   [ldap] ldap_search() failed: LDAP connection lost.
10:39:00 2016 : Info:   [ldap] Attempting reconnect
10:39:01 2016 : Auth: Login incorrect (mschap: External script says ): [someusername] (from client astaro port 0 via TLS tunnel)
10:39:01 2016 : Auth: Login incorrect: [someusername] (from client astaro port 1 cli 20-E4-B8-78-8E-32)
```

However, the ldap error appears to be "normal" for the daily HUP routine and it may just as well happen that the next log entry after "Attempting reconnect" is a "Login OK". Also, I don't see a hint that the reconnection attempt might have failed (I would have expected at least a warning in that case).
I do not see anything special at the AD server.

Comment: Could you post the full output? And maybe the server's logging output?

Comment: @MaximeB I added more of the surrounding log messages (which are not different from the times when all is fine). If with *server* you mean the AD server - there seems to be nothing special

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure about the underlying reason, but since a service restart has so far always helped, I edited `/etc/logrotate.d/freeradius` and changed the `postrotate` action from `reload`to `restart`.
To verify the positive effect faster, I will also change `weekly`to `daily` for a while.

Comment: This is a bug, it was fixed several years ago. FreeRADIUS 2.1.12 is _ancient_, and you should upgrade to version 3, or at least the latest version 2.